# Keep Image and text adjacent to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/9nfb0gj3/

Without using flexbox, I want to be able to keep the image size static and the paragraph next to it.  Right now, the paragraph moves to the next line when re-sizing, how do I keep them next to each other at all times?

```css
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
p{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis placerat ex eros. Maecenas sit amet tellus vitae lacus facilisis varius pretium non sem. Ut non metus tincidunt, rhoncus dolor ut, suscipit arcu. Vestibulum dictum erat metus, nec euismod sem sagittis malesuada. Aenean tristique aliquet euismod. Nullam ultrices diam vel eros bibendum, in tincidunt felis fermentum. Nam vel finibus neque. Nunc ac ligula congue, porttitor arcu sit amet, molestie mi. In dignissim suscipit ligula, a sollicitudin metus lobortis ut. Duis mattis turpis eu purus ultricies, id efficitur enim aliquam.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do like this, where you set `white-space: nowrap` on the `box` and remove `float: left` on your `img` and `p`. I also added `vertical-align: top` on the `img` to have it top aligned.

The `white-space: nowrap` does the trick, telling for inline elements not to break line.

```css
.box {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
p{
  white-space: normal;
  display:inline-block;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis placerat ex eros. Maecenas sit amet tellus vitae lacus facilisis varius pretium non sem. Ut non metus tincidunt, rhoncus dolor ut, suscipit arcu. Vestibulum dictum erat metus, nec euismod sem sagittis malesuada. Aenean tristique aliquet euismod. Nullam ultrices diam vel eros bibendum, in tincidunt felis fermentum. Nam vel finibus neque. Nunc ac ligula congue, porttitor arcu sit amet, molestie mi. In dignissim suscipit ligula, a sollicitudin metus lobortis ut. Duis mattis turpis eu purus ultricies, id efficitur enim aliquam.</p>
</div>
```

A 2016 variant would be `flex`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
p{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis placerat ex eros. Maecenas sit amet tellus vitae lacus facilisis varius pretium non sem. Ut non metus tincidunt, rhoncus dolor ut, suscipit arcu. Vestibulum dictum erat metus, nec euismod sem sagittis malesuada. Aenean tristique aliquet euismod. Nullam ultrices diam vel eros bibendum, in tincidunt felis fermentum. Nam vel finibus neque. Nunc ac ligula congue, porttitor arcu sit amet, molestie mi. In dignissim suscipit ligula, a sollicitudin metus lobortis ut. Duis mattis turpis eu purus ultricies, id efficitur enim aliquam.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One okay option is to wrap the img in a container and use percentage based widths:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fs0s4n3/

```
.img-container{
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
p{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:70%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that makes the text overlap the image on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the display from `inline-block` to `table` and `table-cell` to achieve this.

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.box > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
p {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis placerat ex eros. Maecenas sit amet tellus vitae lacus facilisis varius pretium non sem. Ut non metus tincidunt, rhoncus dolor ut, suscipit arcu. Vestibulum dictum erat metus, nec euismod
    sem sagittis malesuada. Aenean tristique aliquet euismod. Nullam ultrices diam vel eros bibendum, in tincidunt felis fermentum. Nam vel finibus neque. Nunc ac ligula congue, porttitor arcu sit amet, molestie mi. In dignissim suscipit ligula, a sollicitudin
    metus lobortis ut. Duis mattis turpis eu purus ultricies, id efficitur enim aliquam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and efficient ... and I would drop the `table-layout: fixed` and add `vertical-align: top;` to the cells.

Comment: Cheers, I added the fixed layout because the table wouldn't respect the set widths of the children.

Comment: Okay, `vertical-align` is a good tip though, to make it look better, and fixed, I tried with and without and saw no difference

Answer (score 0):

Playing with margins solves it: https://jsfiddle.net/oweahea8/1/

```
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-right: -100px;
}
p{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```